# convex representation of a combinatorial constraint

Tags: matrices, convexity

I have an optimization problem with a weird constraint as follows. Is it possible to express it in some ways that have convex properties:

matrix $\mathbf{X}$ is either

$[1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0\\
 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0\\
 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]$

or

$[0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0\\
 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0\\
 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]$

Or is it possible to expressed some constraint that for a $3\times 1$ vector, it can have either two zeros or three zeros? Thanks

Comment: Such a constraint *cannot* be convex (otherwise you'd have to admit "two-and-a-half zeros"). You could introduce a convex relaxation, which often (but not always) leads to the desired property of the solution.

Comment: what convex relaxation technique can i use? Any references? Thanks

Comment: You write $X=t A + (1-t)B$, where $A$ and $B$ are the two matrices you list. What you wish to do is to do minimize over $t\in \{0,1\}$, which is non-convex. Convex relaxation would be to minimize over $t\in[0,1]$ instead and hope that the optimal value is either $0$ or $1$ (which it often is, but this depends on the rest of the problem).